# quotient of a centralizer

Tags: group-theory

Suppose $SL_6(K)$ is the simple algebraic group over an algebraically closed field K with a characteristic such that $Z(SL_6(K)) = UV, U, V$ are cyclic of order 2 and 3.

Question: Are the two below equal?

$Z(SL_6(K))/U$ and $Z(SL_6(K)/U)$.

I found a statement saying if $U$ intersects $SL_6'$ trivially, then they should be equal. But here the intersection is $U$. Also direct computation seems useless here.

Comment: Well ${\rm SL}_6(K)$ is perfect, so it follows from the three-subgroups commutator lemma. In general, if $G$ is a perfect group and $Z \le Z(G)$, then $Z(G/Z) = Z(G)/Z$.